# Initialising vector of vectors (both outer vector and inner ones)

Tags: c++, vector

There's a lot of similar questions to this here but I did not really find anything that would answer my question in particular.

I have a vector of vectors as an attribute of a class. Another attribute is `bucket_count`. I want to initialise the vector of vectors to the size of `bucket_count` and then initialise each of the vectors inside it to a single "".

Currently, I have

```
class QueryProcessor {
private:    
    int bucket_count;
    // store all strings in one vector
    vector<vector<string> > hash_table(bucket_count);
```

but this does not compile (throws `error: unknown type name 'bucket_count'`)

Removing that if compiles just fine, but eventually will seg fault. I've traced it with the debugger and it seems like it's here

```
.
.
.
} else if (query.type == "add") {
                // Check if string already in table
                for (int i = 0; i < hash_table[hash].size(); i++) { // throws EXEC_BAD_ACCESS here
                    if (hash_table[hash][i] == query.s) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
.
.
.
```

I think it's probably due to not initialising the vectors, hence the question above.

EDIT: Forgot to state I wanted a way of doing it without a for loop

Comment: How many elements do you want per `vector<string>`?

Comment: At the start, each could have zero elements (I will `push_back` as the program runs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a class definition, `vector<vector<string>> hash_table(bucket_count);` declares a function that takes a `bucket_count` and returns a `vector<vector<string>>`.

Initialise in the constructor:

```
QueryProcessor:: QueryProcessor(int count)
    : bucket_count(count),
      hash_table(bucket_count, vector<string>(1))
{
}
```

Comment: Or `vector<vector<string>> hash_table = vector<vector<string>>(bucket_count, vector<string>(1));`